# High-speed channel design

Tags: pcb-design, high-speed

I am currently designing a host board for SFP+ modules. My premise is that I have never designed for high speed therefore I looked up online for application notes and sample boards.

I have mainly 3 questions regarding how should I treat the 100ohm traces:

1. **Antipad design** I found [here](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/programmable/support-resources/bulk-container/pdfs/literature/an/an689.pdf) a useful guide on how to choose the size for an antipad beneath DC blocking capacitors. Is it more correct to choose antipad dimension with respect to pad sizes and their relative distance or should one use the actual capacitor's size? I personally think the former option is the more appropriate one

[image]
2. **SMD connector antipad design** How would you apply similar formulas to compute the size of the antipad to place beneath the SFP smd connector?

3. **Ground planes and SFP module cage** The design of the board has both a Chassis and a digital ground nets. The former one is directly attached to the sfp module cage element and the second is the digital GND used by the actual module and the rest of the board digital section. Is it correct to "shield" differential pair traces from the sfp module with a digital GND plane? I also found a board that uses chassis for the same purpose.

Edit: added image

Answer (score 5):

> Is it more correct to choose antipad dimension with respect to pad sizes and their relative distance or should one use the actual capacitor's size? I personally think the former option is the more appropriate one

The pad size is much more important. The bottom surface of the pad, facing the ground/reference layer on a lower layer, is what determines the capacitance of the pad.

The vertical sides of the component can also have a small effect because they will produce a small fringe capacitance with nearby copper areas. But this effect is small compared to the capacitance between the pad and the reference layer.

> I found here a useful guide on how to choose the size for an antipad beneath DC blocking capacitors.

I would not trust this guide. It simply gives recommended dimensions for the vias and antipads (assuming you're looking at the section titled "Midline Vias") without consideration of the particular material stack-up you might be using. The recommended dimensions were likely optimized for the stack-up of some specific board designed at Altera/Intel, but aren't optimized for the stack-up **you** are using.

For SFP+ design (10-25 Gbps) it's really necessary to optimize features like these in a 3D simulator rather than relying on rules of thumb or empirical formulas.

> SMD connector antipad design How would you apply similar formulas to compute the size of the antipad to place beneath the SFP smd connector?

Crudely, you cut out the antipads deep enough (through enough layers) so that the top layer pad is equivalent to a 50-ohm trace referenced to the bottom of the "well" you've cut in the layers underneath.

But again, this only gives a rough idea of how many anti-pad layers you need to cut. To get good results you should optimize and verify the design using a 3D simulator.

> Is it correct to "shield" differential pair traces from the sfp module with a digital GND plane? I also found a board that uses chassis for the same purpose.

I'm not clear exactly what you are proposing (an image in your question post might help clarify), but you cannot use the chassis ground as the reference for your digital traces. They must reference the digital ground. There should only be a high-impedance connection between the two grounds, so any return currents on the chassis ground wouldn't be able to transfer to the digital ground to return to the source of the digital signals.

Whether this means you should "shield" the traces from the chassis ground or not depends on how far you can keep the traces from the chassis ground otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have now added the image i was referring to for calculating the antipad dimensions beneath dc blocking caps (Section Surface Mount Components). I am avoiding vias for the moment. It also suggests to cut the plane where the proximity with the cap is lower than 0.75*Wc. Do you think i should not follow these guidelines? 
Unfortunately I am not sure I am able to access a 3D simulator:
with "shield" I meant pouring a GND plane all around the differential traces and eventually using vias to connect it to the GND plane of the layer below.

Comment: @amsi, Sorry I realized I didn't answer the specific question you asked --- I've updated my answer. The guidelines from Intel are reasonable. If you're using a driver or receiver with EQ capabilities, they will probably let you pass data without errors. If you're trying to build a test fixture make a standard MCB (module compliance test board), you'll be much better off if you can do some 3D simulation and optimization.

Comment: Thanks. A side question: how about keeping traces as short as possible? Should I consider using curved profiles for corners? According to the current design, these 100ohm diff traces are about 35mm long...

Comment: Is it recommended to compute pads impedance using differential pair simulator (with target impedance 100ohms) or rather is better off considering SMD SFP connector pads independently (with a target impedance 50ohms)?

Comment: @amsi, usually there is a big enough gap between pads that it won't matter which way you do it. If it's easy with the tools you have, use the differential pair simulation.